# Detach an object from a ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my MVVM project, I use as a ItemSource of my Datagrid an ObservableCollection and for the SelectItem, an objet type BankAcount :

In my VM :

```
[RaisePropertyChanged]
public virtual BankAccount SelectedBankAccount { get; set; }

[RaisePropertyChanged]
public virtual ObservableCollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
```

In my View

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="Datagrid"  Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBankAccount}"  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding BankAccounts}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <UC:DataGridEditColumn/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Code}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libellé" Binding="{Binding Path=Wording}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compte Epargne" Binding="{Converter:DisplayBoolToYesNoConverter Investment,Oui,Non}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

when I change my Object since my VM, I would like it does not change my collection...

Comment: I Suspect, you can achieve your requirement by making the property as ReadOnly ( Private set ) in Underlying model. Please ignore if this is not matches your requirement.

Comment: I can not do that.

The user click on a line in the datagrid. This displays a side to him page with the details of this object, it can then edit then valid modification. The trouble is that once it will change one of these properties, will change in the DataGrid when he has not validated these changes.

Comment: Can you more code of VM where you change the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Please improve your question, in you first comment it becomes clear: you have a master detail binding: when you select a row in the datagrid the fields of the row become editable in a side panel. You do not want the data in de datagrid to update before the user has validated the edits by pressing some sort of 'OK' button.

There are several approaches to this:

- Simply use a different viewmodel for the side panel. Fill its properties from the `SelectedBankAccount` when this changes. Copy the properties of the separate viewmodel back to the properties the datagrid is bound to once the user has validated his changes.
- Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` in the Binding expressions in XAML. Do some reading about how to make this work as you now have to trigger updates to the datagrid in code.